# remove dot notation from ng-repeat grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I did a simple [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RffdYwoEB4zxSAWyd8JP?p=preview) that to show my issue. On my page I need to render some properties which I get from api call. This properties have keys 'id' and 'name'.
I need to render all properties except 'id' and for this purposes I'm using angular filter like here

```
 <form style="padding: 15px">
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div ng-repeat="k in rowKeys | filter: '!id'" ng-model="rowValue">
      <label for="rowValue" class="col-sm-2">{{k}}:</label>
      <div class=" col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control rowValue" id="rowValue" value="{{rowData[k]}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData" ng-disabled="!rowValue">Submit</button>
</form>
```

but it shows me some keys thru dot notation such

```
study.name
```

I was trying to replace it with pure javascript replace, but got an error

```
replace is not a function
```

How could I remove '.name' from all keys on my page?

Comment: Do you want a filter that actually changes the data set you get back from the array?  Or just a display filter to manipulate strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could create a simple filter

```
app.filter('hide', function () {
    return function(input, arg) {
        return input.replace(arg, '');
    };
});
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
{{k | hide:'.name'}}
```

Filter could probably use some more error handling.

Demonstration: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/0UpnHMMM94AUyxWVAjHi?p=preview)

Comment: whoa, great it is what I need!! Thank you. What's kind of errors? and where could I read about it, cause this docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter has nothing about it

Comment: @Anton i did quick refactoring in filter https://plnkr.co/edit/d6fURuCGttWJYJBbyhd3?p=preview

Comment: @MohanSingh as I can see it takes out errors which Artur mentioned, right?

Comment: @MohanSingh well not exactly what I was thinking. If the input is a string object whether empty or not it has a replace function and if it can't find anything to replace it will return the same string. No errors here. But I was simply guessing that this filter might someday try to call replace on a null or undefined value.

Comment: @ArturKäpp I just added a check to skip unnecessary replace operation. Actually this filter should check for string `angular.isString(input) ? replace : input`. If input value if integer/undefined/null/object/array there will be type error. Make me correct if i am wrong.

Comment: @MohanSingh Tested the performance of these things just for the fun of it. Here are the results: https://jsfiddle.net/st1hmmun/ . If most of the data doesn't get replaced then I guess your solution is faster and mine would be slower. Opposite is also true. So the OP can choose. From his current example and my test results I guess he should also check the `indexOf` together with `isString`.